# HTTP authenticating to Azure Easy Tables (Azure App Services tables)

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Services service set up with many Easy Tables. I'm accessing the data from these Easy Tables *externally*, from a node.js app running on a completely separate server.

I can access the tables using just basic http requests of the format `https://[app service name].azure-mobile.net/tables/${table-name}?${odata-query}`, and I can use `post` and `patch` requests to add / change lines on the tables too.

However, I can only do the above on tables that I have explicitly set to require **no authentication** - tables where I've set the permissions to **`everyone`**. Obviously this isn't ideal. How can I make a request to the server that will work for permission levels of `Only authenticated users` or `Anybody with the application key`? I'm fine with either of those options, would prefer to use the easier one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr use the `"X-ZUMO-APPLICATION"` as an http header

---

I've found the answer to my own question. I think I didn't give @adrian-hall enough information to give me the answer that would satisfy me most, so I'll give some context here:

I started out with Azure Mobile Services, before they migrated to Azure App Services, and I was using the Easy Tables primarily in the context of a set of Windows Store apps. Initially, my Easy Tables were set to 'Anybody with the application key', and in order to consume the tables in my apps, I was given this bit of code, along with a MobileServiceClient Nuget package:

```
var client = new window.WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
    "https://[my service name].azure-mobile.net/",
    "[application key]"
);
```

Later, I made some tables on the same App Service that I wanted to access via http, not inside my Windows Store app, but I couldn't figure out how to use the application key to authenticate, so I had to set permissions to 'everyone'. But obviously that's pretty nasty - anybody who finds out the url and the table name can read, write, and delete lines from any of my tables that have that permission level!

But I've had them with that setting for months now, with no hitch - I guess my business isn't an interesting target for hackers or whatever.

But I decided I wanted a bit more security anyway, and I wanted to authenticate with *just the application key* so that I wouldn't have to change any of my existing apps.

I started digging around in the Nuget Package for MobileServiceClient on my Windows Store app and found that a `MobileServiceClient` object has a `withFilter` method, which I could give a callback so that I can see the request before it goes out. I managed to find the request so that I can look at the url and headers to see the authentication details, and it turns out it's just a simple header: `"X-ZUMO-APPLICATION": '[application key]'`. Just using that is the perfect solution for me. Now I can set all my tables to 'anybody with the application key' instead of 'everyone' and just have that bit extra security. HTTPS headers are encrypted, so that's enough security for me.

Answer (score 0):

Under Easy Tables is a Node.js backend that you can edit.  The SDK for this Node.js backend is in the GitHub repo - https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-node.

In that repo is a number of samples.  One of those is an API Key: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/api-key

You can also implement Azure App Service Authentication, which allows you to create a client API.  You will need to generate a ZUMO token, probably within a custom API, then pass the ZUMO token in as the X-ZUMO-AUTH header.  This allows you to use the 'authenticated' option in Easy Tables.

You can use either or both of these techniques.